# networkit bipartite graph connected components only when 2 or more common edges

Tags: graph, graph-theory, bipartite, connected-components, networkit

I'm new to the graphs, but trying to get my path through.
Basically, the idea is very simple - we have "transactions" with multiple "features" and need to assign the same Id to transactions, which have 2 or more common features (same values). The number of "transactions" is about 5500 000 records.
For example:

| Transaction | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

- Here only transactions 0 and 1 have 2 common features, so they should be combined with same id.

| Transaction | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

My first approach was to create a graph with all nodes (transactions), then in dataframe filter out matching pairs with duplicates in 2 or more features and create edges for those nodes. But here I face an issue that it's impossible to process so huge dataframe in normal amount of time, even with multiprocessing.
So, the second approach is to create a bipartite graph where source nodes - transactions and target nodes - features.
Then I was able to extract connected components but the result groups were too huge, as transactions even with a single common edge were grouped to the same Id.
Now I'm struggling with the task of how to get connected source nodes that have 2 or more common target features..
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi! Interesting. How many feature columns do you have and how many distinct values per feature?

Comment: Also what happens if you have the following three transactions? 1:{A: 1, B: 1, C: 1, D:1}, 2:{A: 1, B: 1, C: 2, D:2}, 3:{A: 2, B:2, C: 2, D:2}. Do all three transactions end with the same id?

Comment: About 5-8 feature columns.
Yes, all 3 as "connected component"  -  same Id.

Comment: And how many distinct values per column?

Comment: If the number of distinct values per column is not too high, you could convert each row to an array of bits using [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder), and then if two arrays of bits are encoded into integers `x` and `y`, you can test if `x` and `y` have two or more features in common by doing `z = x & y; z &= (z-1)`; now `z` is nonzero iff x and y have at least two features in common.

Comment: Thank you Stef! Interesting idea, I will try.
Unfortunately I have high cardinality so aprx from 5mln it's about 3mln  unique values..